# system.js import from another folder

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I have `public/index.html` and `src/app.js`.

Inside `index.html` i have the following `system.js` call to load `app.js`

`<script>System.import('../src/app');</script>`

It fails with the following error:

`GET https://registry.jspm.io/src/app.js 404 (Not Found)`

What should be the syntax to load files from another folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have forgotten a few other things:

1) you must import *system.js* (auto installed with jspm init)

2) you must include your `config.js` (auto installed with jspm init)

```
        <script src="../jspm_packages/system.js"></script>

        <script src="../config.js"></script>

        <script>
            System.import('client/index').catch(console.log.bind(console));
        </script>
```

3) see how my import says 'client/index' it means my folder structure looks like this:

[image]

4) Now lastly the `config.js` has base path (this is from where your system.import will start; regardless of where the index.html file is.)

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/",
  "transpiler": "traceur",
  "paths": {
    "*": "*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*.js"
  }
});
```

one of these should fix everything. I think it's #2